Compatibility between vmargin and pdfpages?
I'm trying to include a PDF (a cover page) at the beginning of my document but the PDF is shifted both to the left and to the top.
I'm using vmargin to handle my margins and pdfpages for PDF inclusion and apparently the problem comes from the compatibility between the two.
An example of what I'm trying to do that should show the problem:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
 \usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
 \usepackage{vmargin}

\begin{document}
 \includepdf{test.pdf}
 
 \setmarginsrb{3.cm}{3.cm}{2.cm}{2.cm}{1.cm}{1.cm}{1.75cm}{1.75cm}
 \renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.05}
 \renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.95}
 \renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.95}
 \renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.8}
 \setcounter{totalnumber}{5}
 
 \chapter*{Title}
 Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet
 
\end{document} 

"test.pdf" is a simple PDF created with Word with "test" written on the top line of a blank page. I can upload it if you want but I really don't think that's necessary.
The problem shows wherever \includepdf{test.pdf} is put.
I know that:

the whole margin management is overly complicated (I inherited from another source without really understanding all that is going on)
it would work using geometry instead of vmargin

But: the document (a pretty long one) is almost finished and I'm really satisfied with the margins as they are. I tried to reproduce them with geometry but all the results I got were far from the desired layout and moves everything (especially the illustrations) all over the place (I tried something in the likes of \usepackage[a4paper, twoside, hmargin={3cm, 2cm}, vmargin={3cm, 2cm}, headheight=1cm, headsep=1cm, footskip=1.75cm]{geometry}).
So my question is: is my problem inherent to vmargin and pdfpages (as another post suggests)? If so, could someone help me setting up geometry so that it reproduces what vmargin is currently doing?

welcome! don't use vmargin ;). add geometry with the options pass,verbose still with vmargin. get the dimensions from either your console or the log. geometry will give you a list of the dimensions you're currently using. don't copy these verbatim. just copy enough to sort things. if you copy too many, geometry will be unhappy it has nothing to calculate and you risk conflicts. some of the output will be unsuitable for geometry options as it translates those into the underlying results. but getting the current dimensions is key.

you can use example files from the mwe package to ensure everyone has them.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200123/4427

By default vmargin changes \hoffset and \voffset to change the margins, which is a really bad idea, because only packages like crop should use \hoffset and \voffset. But you can use option shiftmargins to avoid this:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
 \usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
 \usepackage[shiftmargins]{vmargin}

\begin{document}
 \includepdf{example-image}
 
 \setmarginsrb{3.cm}{3.cm}{2.cm}{2.cm}{1.cm}{1.cm}{1.75cm}{1.75cm}
 \renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.05}
 \renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.95}
 \renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.95}
 \renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.8}
 \setcounter{totalnumber}{5}
 
 \chapter*{Title}
 Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet
 
\end{document} 


BTW: IMHO with this settings your foot is outside the page area, AFAIK.
Nevertheless, I would always recommend to not use vmargin but geometry (foot position fixed):
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
%\usepackage[shiftmargins]{vmargin}

\usepackage[left=3cm,top=5cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm,headheight=1cm,headsep=1cm,bottom=3.5cm,footskip=1.75cm]{geometry}

% Moved all settings to the document preamble 
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.05}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.95}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.95}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.8}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{5}

\begin{document}
 \includepdf{example-image}
 
 \chapter*{Title}
 Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet
 
\end{document} 


And no, pdfpages should not change it's behavior, because then it would not work correctly with packages like crop.

Thank you! That works!
Yeah, one thing I've learned from this is that  geometry is far more efficient that vmargin. I guess I'll save myself some trouble by using it directly next time I start a document.

@Gypaètemoustachu Not only geometry is more efficient than vmargin: it's much more user friendly. Can you remember the order of arguments in \setmarginsrb without looking at the manual? Can you remember (or interpret) textwidth=..., textheight=... and so on?
